# Суммирование элементов двумерной матрицы Python

Tags: python, массивы

Задание заключается в том, чтобы для матрицы `NxM`, где `N, M < 1000`, просуммировать `K` (`K < 100000`) наборов элементов, заключенных в прямоугольнике, углы которого задаются координатами (`x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2`).

То есть для матрицы

```
1 2 3  
2 4 6  
7 8 9
```

и координат (1, 2, 1, 3) это будет прямоугольник

```
1 2  
2 4  
7 8
```

Мой код работает, но недостаточно быстро (самые объемные тесты в системе не укладываются во время), numpy использовать нельзя. Есть ли какие-то способы ускорить выполнение?

```
def build_y(cx, fx, lx, cy, fy, ly):
    if fy == ly:
        if fx == lx:
            t[cx][cy] = a[fx][fy]
        else:
            t[cx][cy] = t[cx*2][cy] + t[cx*2+1][cy];
    else:
        my = int((fy + ly) / 2)
        build_y (cx, fx, lx, cy*2, fy, my)
        build_y (cx, fx, lx, cy*2+1, my+1, ly)
        t[cx][cy] = t[cx][cy*2] + t[cx][cy*2+1]

def build_x(cx, fx, lx):
    if fx != lx:
        mx = int((fx + lx) / 2)
        build_x (cx*2, fx, mx)
        build_x (cx*2+1, mx+1, lx)
    build_y (cx, fx, lx, 1, 0, m-1)

def sum_y (cx, cy, tfy, tly, fy, ly):
    if fy > ly:
        return 0
    if fy == tfy and tly == ly:
        return t[cx][cy]
    tmy = int((tfy + tly) / 2)
    return sum_y(cx, cy*2, tfy, tmy, fy, min(ly, tmy)) + sum_y(cx, cy*2+1, tmy+1, tly, max(fy, tmy+1), ly)

def sum_x(cx, tfx, tlx, fx, lx, fy, ly):
    if fx > lx:
        return 0
    if fx == tfx and tlx == lx:
        return sum_y(cx, 1, 0, m-1, fy, ly)
    tmx = int((tfx + tlx) / 2)
    return sum_x(cx*2, tfx, tmx, fx, min(lx, tmx), fy, ly) + sum_x(cx*2+1, tmx+1, tlx, max(fx, tmx+1), lx, fy, ly)

fin = open('input.txt', 'r').read().split()
n = int(fin[0])
m = int(fin[1])
k = int(fin[2])
a = []
b = []
t = [0]*4*n
for i in range(4*n):
    t[i] = [0]*4*m
for i in range(n):
    a.append([int(j) for j in fin[3+i*m:3+i*m+m]])
build_x(1, 0, n-1)
for i in range(k):
    b.append([int(j) for j in fin [3+n*m+4*i:3+n*m+4*i+4]])
for i in range(k):
    print(sum_x(1, 0, n-1, b[i][0]-1, b[i][2]-1, b[i][1]-1, b[i][3]-1))
```

Comment: А почему такой огромный код? О_о все это делается всего в одну строчку: http://ideone.com/nDutKg `sum( [ sum( arr[k][x1:x2] ) for k in range(y1,y2) ] )`

Comment: Все это должно считаться за доли секунды на таких малых данных менее 1000... Видимо много строк кода мешает...

Comment: @ReinRaus пробовал этот вариант, он работает быстрее на небольших тестах, но медленнее при больших

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что может быть что-то быстрее без numpy

Comment: @ReinRaus вот и я:(
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Как происходит тестирование? К одной матрице применяется множество операций суммирования разных срезов? Если так, то можно попробовать оптимизировать как-нибудь.

Comment: @ReinRaus да, матрица одна, а наборов координат несколько

Comment: первое что приходит в голову- кэш. Например 5% от длины массива. То есть для массива 100х100 размер ячейки кэша 5х5, граничные значения среза выходящие за пределы ячеек кэша вычисляются полным перебором. Для целой ячейки идет запрос к кэшу. Если значение было вычислено ранее, то оно возвращается, если не вычислено - вычисляется. Максимальное увеличение производительности таким путем на множестве запросов - 25 раз (зависит от размера ячейки кэша).

Answer (score 3):

Пусть исходная матрица - a.
Используем дополнительную матрицу b такого же размера (или на 1 больше по каждому измерению - см. далее). В b[x][y] будем хранить сумму элементов квадрата от элемента [0][0] до [x][y] включительно.
Такую матрицу матрицу можно построить за время O(N * M).

Далее ответ на искомый вопрос можно выдавать за линейное время:

```
result = b[x2][y2] - b[x1-1][y2] - b[x2][y1-1] + b[x1-1][y2-1]
```

Общая сложность задачи: O(M * N + K), улучшить оценку невозможно, так как как минимум нужно считать матрицу и считать K раз индексы.

Замечу три вещи:

1) в коде я использую питоновский "хак" - строю матрицу размером на 1 больше.
Это позволяет мне не беспокоиться об обращении к элементам с индексом -1 (b[-1][-1] - это b[N-1][M-1] - последний элемент матрицы) - все эти элементы равны нулю.
На каком-нибудь C++ такое не прошло бы - пришлось бы делать проверки (i < 0, j < 0 и т.д.)

2) в коде я использовал общепринятые соглашения при написании таких задач:
N - количество строк (и индексы - x1, x2), M - количество столбцов (и индексы y1, y2). Индексы начинаются с нуля (чтобы не писать b[x2-1][y2-1] и т.д.). Именно поэтому `x1, x2, y1, y2 = 0, 2, 0, 1`

3) все манипуляции можно сделать без дополнительной памяти - в самой исходной матрице.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [7, 8, 9]] # для проверки
N, M = 3, 3 # для проверки

b = [[0 for j in range(M + 1)] for i in range(N + 1)]

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        b[i][j] = b[i-1][j] + b[i][j-1] - b[i-1][j-1] + a[i][j]

# для ответа на вопрос задачи - сумма чисел в прямоугольнике (x1, x2, y1, y2)
x1, x2, y1, y2 = 0, 2, 0, 1
result = b[x2][y2] - b[x1-1][y2] - b[x2][y1-1] + b[x1-1][y2-1]

print(result)
```