# Сложение смежных элементов двумерного массива Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, numpy

Есть массив

```
m = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

на вход подается матрица `n*m`, на выходе должна получиться матрица такой же размерности но состоящая из суммы смежных элементов.например элемент `[0][0]` новой матрицы `[i-1][j]+[i+1][j]+[i][j-1]+[i][j+1]` это `7+4+3+2=16`.

Вариант вывода:

```
[16, 17, 18]
[19, 20, 21]
[22, 23, 24]
```

Comment: А как получен результат? Откуда, например, взялось 16?

Comment: Пожалуйста укажите сумму возможных последовательностей. Пример S1=1+4+7+4=16

Comment: как вы хотели бы посчитать искомую сумму, приведите формулу или тип того, а то непонятно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Суммирование элементов двумерной матрицы Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458992/%d0%a1%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-python)

Comment: 16 = это сумма всех смежных элементов по осям х и у. Т.е [0][0] новой матрицы равен сумме [i+1]+[i-1]+[j+1]+[j-1]. Т.е 2+3+4+7=16 это первый элемент новой матрицы. Остальные по аналоги

Comment: @StanislavRepin почему 7 это смежный элемент для 1? Они же не соприкасаются. Точно ли требуется сделать именно так как вы говорите? Не должно ли быть в позиции [0][0] у итоговой матрицы 6?

Answer (score 2):

Решал аналогичную задачу на Stepik, давно было дело. Единственная разница с вашим условием в том, что строки подавались пользовательским вводом последовательно и последняя строка содержала строку "end". Мое решение не самое лаконичное, но, возможно, оно поможет вам.

```py
# В этом блоке я просто как бы получаю вашу переменную m, но с пользовательского ввода
enter = input()
matrix = []
while enter != 'end':
  nums = [int(x) for x in enter.split()]
  matrix.append(nums)
  enter = input()

# Затем создаю матрицу такого же размера, но состоящую из нулей
new_matrix = [[0 for j in range(len(i))] for i in matrix]

# А потом наполняю новую матрицу значениями
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if i < len(matrix)-1 and j < len(matrix[i])-1:
            x = sum([matrix[i - 1][j], matrix[i + 1][j], matrix[i][j - 1], matrix[i][j + 1]])

        elif i == len(matrix)-1 and j < len(matrix[i])-1:
            x = sum([matrix[i - 1][j], matrix[0][j], matrix[i][j - 1], matrix[i][j + 1]])

        elif i < len(matrix)-1 and j == len(matrix[i])-1:
            x = sum([matrix[i - 1][j], matrix[i + 1][j], matrix[i][j - 1], matrix[i][0]])

        elif i == len(matrix)-1 and j == len(matrix[i])-1:
            x = sum([matrix[i - 1][j], matrix[0][j], matrix[i][j - 1], matrix[i][0]])

        new_matrix[i][j] = x

# А потом печатаю ответ (так нужно было по условию задачи) 
for row in new_matrix:
    print(*row)
```